# UI Design for web application

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface, angular-ui

I am planning to create a web application based on java, jsp and struts. I have sketched the requirement and how functionality should work and who the target users would be. Even though I am very excited about the application, I am not sure how should I create a good UI design for it.

Shall I go for css as a common way of designing UI's which would be a tedious task to map css to all the elements/tags. Is there any other way of doing it? I am new to this and this would be my first project which I have been planning from very long.

Which technologies should I use in achieving this in regards to design?

Note: Also I want to keep my application light weight rather than using flash content and other sorts

Comment: You can use tweeter's [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for responsive web application which come with multiple ui templates, well you can use it with jsp also but it also nice if you differentiate your ui with servlet and use angularjs([angular ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/))

Comment: are you sure that you want to use jsp?

Comment: I am still flexible to change. Any better idea than jsp ?

Comment: Yes you should try jsf(java server faces) [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/), it solved your ui template problems :) You can use it with bootstrap also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using something like Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

That library will allow you to build some nice user interfaces without having to deal with too much CSS or HTML yourself.

Attempting to roll your own CSS and HTML is just asking for pain. Use a framework like this one and things like cross browser support will be much simpler(pretty much free).

Bootstrap can easily be paired with JSP because you just make the web page output be in bootstrap format. Basically use the CSS classes it defines. For examples:

```
<!-- Indicates a successful or positive action -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>

<!-- Contextual button for informational alert messages -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>

<!-- Indicates caution should be taken with this action -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>

<!-- Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
```

They have similar classes for layout and all kinds of other widgets.

Comment: Sure that's also a possibility. The main reason I suggested bootstrap is that all of the processing seems to be happening server side. In that case, the server can just output HTML with the correct CSS and everything will work. But yes, Jquery UI is another option, especially if more advanced UIs are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the approach of Jon. When you are choosing a CSS frame work consider the paltforms ( desktop, tab and mobile ) and choose the right one.

http://webdesignlike.com/2015/best-free-responsive-html5-frameworks/

http://www.cssnewbie.com/best-free-css3-frameworks-2015/#.VVooCfxVhBc

http://devzum.com/2014/11/20/best-html-css-frameworks/

Go through these links, it will give you a better idea.